# A Riley Riddle that Moves Away

Tags: riddle, word

My prefix is when you jump into a lake

My infix is when you reach the edge of it

My suffix is if you are a nice chap

My whole is always varying

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My prefix is when you jump into a lake

> dive

My infix is when you reach the edge of it

> verge

My suffix is if you are a nice chap

> gent

My whole is always varying

> divergent - growing further apart, not converging.